# How do I combine raster data in different coordinate systems and different cell size into one data set with fine cell size with ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

**input**:

CORINE land use data (cell size 100m x 100m, LAEA coordinates, EU countries) and GLC ("Global Land Cover") data (1km x 1km, WGS84, Europe, land use classes changed to match CORINE data with `reclassify` tool)

**output**:

one land use (discrete values) raster data set with 100m x 100m cells in LAEA coordinates.

**details**:

For EU countries I want the data to remain exactly as it is, with LAEA coordinates and 100m cell size. For non-EU European countries I would like to have the land use data from GLC but in an expanded 100m x 100m raster that is a seamless continuation of the CORINE raster. (I know that the coarser information does not normally justify just splitting one cell up into 100 and giving all of them the same value as the original larger cell. However, for my purposes, this approach makes sense and I really want to do it this way.)

How can I do this with ArcMap? What tools do I need to combine in what order?
`Project` GLC data first, then `merge`?

When I tried to project the GLC data, I always had to have unspecified raster size in order for it to work (10^-3? To account for differently oriented traster cells, I guess). That is not what I want at all. For my purposes, I really need a raster with equally sized "squares". Outside of EU, the information does not need to be absolutely accurate, if some of it gets distorted a bit, that's okay, I just really need a raster with squares. Also, I need to make sure that CORINE data stays exactly the way it is in EU countries.

Comment: You've got five question marks and very little in the way of what you've tried. This is a simple masking exercise, so you can drop the "Is this possible?"

Comment: If this was simple for me, I would not ask the question.. I fail to see how masking would solve the main issue, namely converting the GLC data to LAEA coordinates and reducing cell size while aligning CORINE cells with the new 100m GLC cells. I may be wrong, though, since I am new to GIS and only just now read the arcmap info about masking grids. I tried converting GLC data to LAEA and merging the two data sets, but got the aforementioned problem with raster size.

Comment: The root issue is that you don’t have a single question, as called for in the [Tour]. If you break the goal into the constituent tasks (reproject, resample, mask), you're more likely to find documentation and answers for each step (which will also put you into alignment with the "Focused question / Best answer" model used here)

Comment: I really don't know in which order this should be done. I tried merging without reprojecting, projecting and then merging, but neither approach gave the desired results. I know that my question consist of many details - in order to ask a more general question I would need to understand ArcMap much better. Unfortunately I don't, and the class that is planned at our institute keeps getting postponed. The program is HUGE and it is impossible to read through all the help pages of all the tools that might be relevant to my problem. If you know how to break it down, please tell me :)

Comment: I gave you the order. There isn't much more I can do. A focused question would tackle only one step, and would include exact details of the software used, including the exact command and what about the results were undesired.